# Can a App build using ReactNative or Flutter Run on both Mac and iPhone

Tags: ios, flutter, react-native, macos

Can I use the same project to run an application that was build using React Native or Flutter  on both Mac and iPhone or do I need to build to two separate project for each platform.

or would be it is better to build the app using Swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On flutter you can develop once and distribute on different platforms, including apple's.
On react native you can't